# Scala readLine with prompt displays prompt after line input in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm running Scala **2.10** program through `sbt run` from Windows 7 command line and I see an unexpected behavior while calling `readLine` overload with the prompt. The prompt is shown after the actual line input.

**Source**

```
object MyExample extends App {
  readLine("This prompt is shown after the readline!")
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "hello"\n
\n
version := "1.0"\n
\n
```

**Output**

```
asdf
This prompt is shown after the readline!
```

Is there something I don't understand or is it a bug? It seems to be working as expected from IDEA.

Sbt version: 0.13.1

Comment: Can you run `sbt about` to know your SBT version and plugins? I've experienced an issue with SBT that was caused by a plugin not SBT itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before with [giter8](https://github.com/n8han/giter8).  The work around is to do your own print, flush the output stream, and then read.  See [this pull request](https://github.com/n8han/giter8/pull/124) for an example of the workaround.

[Someone has fixed it](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/81d11514f40314d8a64c009c0810f08f695b3e18) in the scala source about a month ago.  I don't have any idea when we will see that fix, tho.

Comment: It's worth to mention about adding `scalaVersion := "2.11.0-RC1"` to `build.sbt` as a solution (I couldn't check it out myself as I don't have access to Win7 now).